# How to Pan across a set of images at intervals

Tags: ipad, uiimageview, nstimer

I want to show UIPanGestureRecognizer(Panning effect) on UIImageView without touch event.

thanks

Comment: how do you expect to process a gesture without a touch event? A gesture IS a touch event.

Comment: can you give me any idea for panning effect?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid a touch event? Give us a bit more to work with here.

Comment: my problem is panning effect. I have 4 images and i want to change image every 10 sec. between 10 sec. image show panning effect. So I want to show UIPanGestureRecognizer without touch event.

Comment: So you want the image to fly to the left and the new image to come onto the screen from the right?

Comment: if I were you, I'd remove all association with UIPanGestureRecognizer from your question title and text. What you want is nothing to do with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've gathered through your comments:

What you need is to encapuslate several UIImageViews within a UIScrollView. Then you'd need to enable Scrolling on the ScrollView but disable User Interaction. You can do this through the XIB.

Then you'd need to set up an [NSTimer](http://borkware.com/quickies/one?topic=NSTimer) and in the handler function add an animation as below:

```
NSTimer *timer;

timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 10.00
             target: self
             selector: @selector(handleTimer:)
             userInfo: nil
             repeats: YES];

- (void) handleTimer: (NSTimer *) timer
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
        animations:^{ 
            ImageView1.x+=ImageView1.width;
            ImageView2.x+=ImageView2.width;
            ImageView3.x+=ImageView3.width;
        }];
}
```

**FYI** A UIPanGestureRecognizer actually recognises the touch and sweep left/right movement. You can pan an image or a view or anything by moving it's coordinates in an animation block as above; but it's got nothing to do with UIPanGestureRecognizer because that controls the actual touch event.